# With Xcode 6.2 getting ibtool failed with error code 255

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

My project was working fine in Xcode Version 6.1.1. I had upgraded the Xcode to 6.2 and tried to build the same project for iOS8. It gave me the following error :
`Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool failed with exit code 255`.

I had followed the suggestion given in the below link

```
Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool failed with exit code 255
```

Like  :
a. deleted my app and restarted it 
b. Cleaned the project and build 
c. Checked for the xib file error

Still getting the same error.
But if I revert back to previous Xcode version it works fine.

Comment: what is the error? it should be in build log

Comment: In the build log , for one of the xib file i see the issue - >  CompileXIB TermsAndConditionsTVC/TableViewCells/FooterPromptCell.xib the error msg is prompted - Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool failed with exit code 255

Comment: @odemolliens Can you upload the xib file that is causing the issue?  You probably have an unsupported tag or configuration in there.

Comment: @odemolliens ibtool is used with interface builder documents, xibs and storyboards.  It has to be related to one or the other.  If you have a storyboard, can you post that?

Answer (score 1):

Hi also Facing the same Issue:

Try This it will works for me:

Create a ZipFile of Project

when you close Xcode 6.1

Commit you Xcode Project..

When Open Xcode 6.2

Discard all the changes.

Run the Code.It will Work.

It is Xcode StoryBoard issue.